# Erro ao ler caracteres

Tags: c

Em vez do código ler as três variáveis char, ele lê 2 e imprime a 1ª.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ch1, ch2, ch3;

    puts("Digite 3 caracteres, um apos o outro:");
    scanf("%c%c%c", &ch1, &ch2, &ch3);
    printf("%c\n%c\n%c", ch1, ch2, ch3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Acabei de testar seu programa e está funcionando. Está lendo as 3 letras digitadas e mostrando na tela.

Comment: Posso confirmar o comentário do @Electus. Corri o programa e o `output` é o esperado.

Comment: Isso é bem estranho, pois agora ele lê 2 caracteres e fecha, usei [este](http://www.onlinecompiler.net/) compilador online para testar mas mesmo assim o programa não se comporta corretamente.

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta. Dá uma olhada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é o seguinte: você está teclando *enter* a cada caractere digitado. Não tecle enter, apenas digite um caractere ao lado do outro. E adicione um system("pause") pra você poder visualizar a saída:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char ch1, ch2, ch3;

    puts("Digite 3 caracteres, um apos o outro:");
    scanf("%c%c%c", &ch1, &ch2, &ch3);
    printf("%c\n%c\n%c\n", ch1, ch2, ch3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agora foi, valeu cara! Só vou substituir o system("pause") por getchar() pois estou executando em Gnu/Linux. Obrigado!

Comment: Pensei que tinha que dar enter, quando eu faço isso com números inteiros funciona.

Comment: Se teclar _enter_ ele entende que também é um caractere. De fato é, pois _enter_ é um caractere de escape. Por isso dá a impressão de ler apenas dois caracteres, pois o _enter_ é "invisível".

Comment: Esqueci completamente disso, obrigado de novo.